# How do I get data back from Paypal so I can alter my MySQL database accordingly?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, paypal

I'm just starting out with Paypal, so this is a newbie question.

I've been going through the [instructions for setting up Paypal subscription service](https://www.paypal.com/eBay/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/tech-overview-subscriptions-outside), but I think I'm looking at the wrong thing.

What I want to acheive is to get back some kind of response from Paypal so that I can update the database on my web site to mark a registered user as having paid. Basically I have a flag in the database that says if the user is subscribed or not. I want to ensure that the user is marked as paid so long as their Paypal subscription is maintained.

While the instructions linked above do say how to set up a button to receive a payment, there's nothing there about getting any data back from Paypal.

I know there are terms like *IPN* and *sandbox* that are related to what I'm trying to do, but I can't find clear instructions for how to get started on this process. I'm just circling around and not getting anywhere.

Where do I start on setting this up? Where is there a clear beginner's tutorial?

Also, I'm using PHP/Javascript/MySQL on my website.

Comment: Found this: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted
Look for: `Obtaining Express Checkout Transaction Details`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PayPal's IPN service](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) is what you want to use. I've used it myself to do just what you're looking to do.

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service that
>   sends a notification when a transaction is affected. Once IPN is
>   integrated, sellers can automate their back office so they don’t have
>   to wait for payments to come in to trigger order fulfillment. IPN can
>   send notifications for these transactions:
>
> - Instant payments, including Express Checkout and direct credit card    payments
> - eCheck payments and pending, completed, or denied status payments
> - Pending payments
> - Recurring payments and subscriptions
> - Authorizations
> - Disputes, chargebacks, reversals, and refunds
>
> You can also view notifications on PayPal’s IPN History page and
>   resend them if you need to. As PayPal’s interface for handling
>   purchase confirmation and server-to-server communications, IPN can
>   also be used to manage and customize a variety of APIs and
>   communications, including:
>
> - Customize your website's response to customer purchases in seconds
> - Track customers via IPN "pass-through" variables
> - Notify sellers who deal mostly in software downloads and other digital, online goods
> - Track affiliate sales and commissions
> - Store transaction information in your own database

For more about IPN:

- [Technical Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) (link to new html version of docs on developer central)
- [Instant Payment Notification Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf) (PDF)
- [Code Samples](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if its the same thing, but I just [setup my friends website with Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted), and I wanted to add all paid orders to an orders table in my database.

After I call [SetExpressCheckout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout), and the user is returned to my site after going through the purchase flow on Paypal's side,
I used the information from [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails).

Then, if [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoExpressCheckoutPayment)
is successful (also called from the "callback" page) I then do the appropriate work in my database as far as logging the order details.  For you in this case, it could be updating a record for the user in the database.

Hope that helps a little.