# Where should I execute an UPDATE query when I receive PayPal IPN?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

Following up on [my previous newbie question about Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500689/how-do-i-get-data-back-from-paypal-so-i-can-alter-my-mysql-database-accordingly), I have a new newbie question.

I have succeeded in getting a Paypal sandbox set up, and implemented a PHP "listener" on my server, and when I test my Paypal payment buttons, everything seems to be working fine. So it seems I have the essential skeleton of a payment system happening.

Now I'm a little confused as to how to take it to the next step of customizing it to my needs.

To set up the listener, I just copied [the code offered on Paypal's site](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation). My hope and assumption was that I could find a spot in that code at the point where Paypal is telling me that the payment has come though.

However, it is not clear to me where that point is. Were I to set up some kind of "if" statement based on paid or not paid, I can't see what value I would test on.

All I want to do is if Paypal tells me the person has paid, then a flag in my MySQL database will be marked as "paid". It should be a recurring payment, and so if the next automatic payment fails, then the flag in the database should be marked "unpaid".

Is there a place in their code I can use as the starting point for adding in my own custom actions? Or do I need to use some other code base entirely?

For reference, here is the PHP code in question:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$email = $_GET['ipn_email'];
$header = "";
$emailtext = "";
// Read the post from PayPal and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc'))
{
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
// Handle escape characters, which depends on setting of magic quotes
{
    if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
    {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    }
    else
    {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post back to PayPal to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// Process validation from PayPal
// TODO: This sample does not test the HTTP response code. All
// HTTP response codes must be handles or you should use an HTTP
// library, such as cUrl

if (!$fp)
{ // HTTP ERROR
}
else
{
// NO HTTP ERROR
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            // TODO:
            // Check the payment_status is Completed
            // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // Process payment
            // If 'VERIFIED', send an email of IPN variables and values to the
            // specified email address
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $emailtext .= $key . " = " . $value . "\n\n";
            }
            mail($email, "Live-VERIFIED IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
        }
        else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {
            // If 'INVALID', send an email. TODO: Log for manual investigation.
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $emailtext .= $key . " = " . $value . "\n\n";
            }
            mail($email, "Live-INVALID IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go one step further and implement the TODO steps.

Now, PayPal has a standard pass-through field called item_number. You can use that field to pass your database's order ID:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $OrderID ?>">
```

Since it is a pass-through variable, PayPal will echo back the value of this variable in the IPN. So after you're validated the IPN and gone through the TODO list, update your database:

```
// if ($_POST["payment_status"] == "Completed"
// &&  $_POST["receiver_email"] == the_email_you_use_in_business_field
// &&  etc etc
// )
"UPDATE Orders SET paid = 1 WHERE OrderID = {$_POST[item_number]}"
```

Validate and sanitize the POST variables before using them in database queries.

- [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) -- the variables you send to PayPal via HTML form
- [IPN and PDT Variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) -- the variables you receive in IPNs

## Edit

I now see that you want to process recurring payments. Not straight forward as it seems:

- Go through the variables reference carefully. There are few fields you can use to identify the subscription (custom, invoice, item_number).
- You'll receive multiple IPNs during multiple stages of subscription, including the subscription itself, the first payment, the subsequent payments and when the subscription was terminated.
- Variables passed with each type of payment changes. You must consult the documentation thoroughly to determine exactly what fields you should check for each type of IPN.

Answer (score 2):

Place your database related code inside:

```
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
//your database query here
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this comments:

```
> // TODO:
>             // Check the payment_status is Completed
>             // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
>             // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
>             // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
>             // Process payment
>             // If 'VERIFIED', send an email of IPN variables and values to the
>             // specified email address
```

Put your code here:

```
   if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
   {

    ...

    }
```